# most efficient way to "populate" parent in mongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

If I have a Mongoose schema that holds references what would be the best way to "populate" the parent id when getting children out of the DB

example:

```
const parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String},
  children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child' }],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);

const childSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true }, 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);
```

If I would like to find all the children but have a key with the parent id included how would I do it best?

child example
name: "Fredrik"
parentID: "1212q3123123212"